# Python logging module behaving differently if logging is used before basicConfig

Tags: python

Consider the following piece of code:

```
import logging

logging.info("toto")

logging.basicConfig(level="INFO",
                    format="%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s -"
                    " %(levelname)s"
                    " - [%(funcName)s():%(filename)s:%(lineno)s]"
                    " - %(message)s")
logging.info("info")
logging.error("error")
logging.warning("warn")
logging.debug("debug")
```

The output is the following:

```
$ python mmt_test.py 
ERROR:root:error
WARNING:root:warn
```

However, with the following code:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level="INFO",
                    format="%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s -"
                    " %(levelname)s"
                    " - [%(funcName)s():%(filename)s:%(lineno)s]"
                    " - %(message)s")
logging.info("info")
logging.error("error")
logging.warning("warn")
logging.debug("debug")
```

The output is:

```
$ python mmt_test.py 
2021-12-07 07:44:46,711 - MainThread - INFO - [<module>():mmt_test.py:8] - info
2021-12-07 07:44:46,711 - MainThread - ERROR - [<module>():mmt_test.py:9] - error  
2021-12-07 07:44:46,711 - MainThread - WARNING - [<module>():mmt_test.py:10] - warn
```

In the first code sample, why isn't `basicConfig` applied to the logs ? Does using the `logging` module before using basicConfig prevents to use `basicConfig` afterwards ?

This happens in python `3.5.2`, `3.8.3` and `3.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The call to basicConfig() should come before any calls to debug(), info() etc. As it’s intended as a one-off simple configuration facility, only the first call will actually do anything: subsequent calls are effectively no-ops.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file

This says that the `basicConfig()` call is only one-off. Only the first one will be effective.

> The functions debug(), info(), warning(), error() and critical() will call basicConfig() automatically if no handlers are defined for the root logger.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig

This says that the functions like `debug()`, `info()`, etc, will call the `basicConfig()` automatically if no handler is set.

So based on the above two statements, it is clear that in your first example, when you called `logging.info("toto")`, it automatically calls the `logging.basicConfig()` as no handler is set.

Therefore, on your call of `logging.basicConfig()`, it does nothing, as specified in the docs.

One more relevant quote from the python3 logging docs

> By default, no destination is set for any logging messages. You can specify a destination (such as console or file) by using basicConfig() as in the tutorial examples. If you call the functions debug(), info(), warning(), error() and critical(), they will check to see if no destination is set; and if one is not set, they will set a destination of the console (sys.stderr) and a default format for the displayed message before delegating to the root logger to do the actual message output.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial

**In conclusion**, if you call `logging.info()` or the logging related functions, before setting the formatter and handler using `logging.basicConfig()`, they will just default to the default handler and format.
If you want the message to have specific formatting and handler, you have to call `logging.basicConfig()` before logging anything.